# Arduino to Java communication

Tags: java, arduino

I have an Arduino that sends data to the Java program via serial communication. On power up and rest the Arduino sends invisible data to the serial port that needs purged/cleared etc. I've tried serial flushing from the arduino and from the Java program and neither seems to be working.

This is my Arduino code:

```
void setup() {

delay(2500);
Serial.begin(9600);
flushreceive();
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {

char input;

if (Serial.available()) {
input = Serial.read();

//Turn on the LED.
if(input == '1'){
digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
Serial.print("ON");
flushreceive();
}

//Have the LED blink 10 times.
if(input == '2') {
Serial.print("OX");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(13, LOW);
delay(100);
flushreceive();
}
}

 //Turn off the LED.
 if(input == '3') {
 digitalWrite(13, LOW);
 Serial.print("OFF");
 flushreceive();
 }

 } // END IF SERIAL AVAILABLE
 } // END LOOP

 void flushreceive() {
 while(Serial.available())
 Serial.flush();
 }
```

Below is my Java code that when a button is pressed it sends the code to the Arduino which turns on or off the LED and the Arduino sends back an acknowledgement of an OFF or ON. However, I'm not receiving this. Either half the characters come in or none at all.

```
    //Listener for the blink button.
    btnBlink.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnOn.setBackground(null);
            btnBlink.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            btnOff.setBackground(null);
            //Turns on the #13 pin LED and flashes it 10 times.
            if(comPort.isOpen() == true) {
                InputStream inPut = comPort.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader readBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inPut));
                //Send a 2 to the Arduino and update the user.
                lblStatus.setText("Status: LED Blinking");
                outPut.print("2");
                outPut.flush();
                 byte[] buffer = new byte[2];
                   try {
                         String message = "OX";
                         int len = inPut.read(buffer);
                             if (len > 0) {
                                            message = new String(buffer);
                                            System.out.println(message);
                                           }
    
    
                             if (message.trim().contains("OX")) {
                                btnBlink.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                                outPut.flush();
                               } else {
                                       System.out.println("ERROR!!"));
                                      }

                        } catch (Exception ep) { ep.printStackTrace();   }
                        } else {
                       //Update the status/console if the Arduino hasn't been connected.
                        lblStatus.setText("Status: Connect Arduino");
                        }
                        }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code from Arduino Playground and `rxtx` library to get data from arduino serial to my java program and it worked like magic .

Both link are here:

https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java

http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download

You just need to set the right port number and baud rate(as baud rate is generally:`9600` and com port may vary from device to device for my case it was `COM3`)

Answer (score 0):

- In your Arduino sketch comment out all the "flushreceive();", then upload and open  serial monitor in Arduino IDE, then type 1 and 2 accordingly.

  (i have tested your code using Arduino UNO and it worked after commenting out all the flushreceive();)
- use non-blocking [avdweb_VirtualDelay](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/avdweb_virtual-delay) library instead of delay.
- in java side use [jssc](https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/).jar library for serial communication.
- then in java class implement SerialPortEventListener then process the received data in serialEvent method.
- use serialPort.readBytes() to read from Arduino.
- use serialPort.writeBytes() to write to Arduino.
- take a look at [Ardulink](https://github.com/Ardulink/Ardulink-2) library as well.